# What's the best practice of mergerfs with nfs?

Tags: debian, nfs, performance

I run mergerfs with latest Debian Testing with kernel 5.4.

```
Linux ches-disk0 5.4.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1 (2020-02-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is on a Dell R730 server with 3 disk arrays, CPU is 2 E5-2603v3 and 16GB memory. Each array is hard raid6 and have one zfs pool. Mergerfs combine them together.

```
fuse.mergerfs   defaults,use_ino,allow_other,noforget,cache.files=auto-full,threads=0,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,cache.readdir=true,cache.statfs=60,minfreespace=100G,cache.symlinks=true,fsname=mergerfs,category.create=mfs,func.getattr=newest,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.service
```

I have 2 nodes with slurm, share the mergerfs disk from nfs

```
 *(rw,fsid=1,async,no_subtree_check)
```

Now, when meeting massive continuous I/O, multiple small size files. The mergerfs process take 200-400% cpu and the I/O stuck there for tens of minutes. If I restart the file server, then the job will execute for a period.

So, what's the best practice mergerfs for this case? I notice the use_ino and noforget from manual, and use async for nfs server.

Comment: see some error in messages
nfsd4_process_open2 failed to open newly-created file! status=13